# How to return a error from a goroutine (through channels)

Tags: go

When i write a function in Go, it should return a value and an error like

```golang
func createHashedPassword(password string) (string, error) {
  //code
}
```

I want to execute this createHashedPassword in a goroutine and I think to pass data via channel.
But my question is, how can I handle error here or in the goroutine?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's common to bundle multiple outputs into a struct, and return them together over a single channel.

```
type Result struct {
    Message string
    Error error
}

ch := make(chan Result)
```

Comment: Do I pass here a reference type right? I have read somewhere, when it is possible to avoid pass reference type over channel, it is true?

Comment: that's incorrect, and do you mean a pointer? There's no official concept of "reference type', but slices and maps are often called "reference types". You can pass whatever you want through a channel, with the same semantics as any other call or assignment.

Comment: The Go catchphrase is "Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating".  Channels give you a way to communicate between threads without needing to protect against accessing the same memory at the same time.  So you can share a pointer, but (if I understand right) do so in a way that means you won't have two or more threads accessing that memory at the same time.  One thread could receive a pointer, do work on the memory it points to, then stop working on it and pass that pointer on through a channel.  Only one thread working on that pointer at any given time.

Answer (score 34):

You can pass in an error channel as well as a result channel.

```
errors := make(chan error, 0)
results := make(chan string, 0)

password := "test"

go func() {
    result, err := createHashedPassword(string password)
    if err != nil {
        errors <- err
        return
    }

    results <- result
}()

// do something else

// When you are ready to read from goroutine do this:
select {
    case err := <- errors:
        println(err)
    case res := <- results:
        println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here are my two preferred ways:

**Two channels, wrapped**

This is the "two channels" way, but wrapped into a function to make it look similar to the common pattern:

```
func createHashedPasswordAsynchronously(password string) (chan string, chan error) {
    resultCh := make(chan string)
    errorCh := make(chan error)

    go func(password string) {
        //code
        if err != nil {
            errorCh <- errors.New("Does not compute")
        } else {
            resultCh <- "8badf00d"
        }
    }(password)

    return resultCh, errorCh
}
```

And called like this:

```
resultCh, errorCh := createHashedPasswordAsynchronously("mysecret")
select {
case result := <-resultCh:
    storeHashedPassword(result)
case err := <-errorCh:
    log.Println(err.Error())
}
```

**Anonymous struct**

This is the "anonymous struct" way, similar to @saward's answer, but without naming the struct members explicitly:

```
go func(password string, ch chan struct {
    string
    error
}) {
    //code
    if err != nil {
        ch <- struct {
            string
            error
        }{"", errors.New("Does not compute")}
    } else {
        ch <- struct {
            string
            error
        }{"8badf00d", nil}
    }
}("mysecret", ch)

r := <-ch
if r.error != nil {
    log.Println(r.error.Error())
} else {
    storeHashedPassword(r.string)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

(since I cannot comment yet...)

I echo what JimB said with:

```
type Result struct {
    Message string
    Error error
}

ch := make(chan Result)
```

The trouble with two separate channels, one for the result, and another for the error, is that (as I understand) it won't support concurrent threads out of the box.

You could, for example, have two threads sending data at the same time, where the replies get out of order.  That is, you receive the result from thread 1 first, but the error from thread 2 first.

It's easy to create new types like JimB suggested, and should work well with goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

One of the common patterns is to pass a error channel and a result channel to the function:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  password := "blah blah"
  resultChan := make(chan string)
  errChan := make(chan error)

  go createHashedPassword(password, resultChan, errChan)

  // Do some other stuff

  select {
  case err := <-errChan:
    fmt.Println(err)
  case res := <-resultChan:
    fmt.Println(res)
  }
}

func createHashedPassword(password string, resultChan chan string, errChan chan error) {
  // your code for hashing and stuff
  if err != nil {
    errChan <- err
    return
  }
  resultChan <- result
}
```

---

You can also make channels inside the `createHashedPassword` as [AndreKR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476074/andrekr) said,

or call the `createHashedPassword` inside an anonymous goroutine as [Ian Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325180/ian-davis) said.

---

There is also some other possible patterns, and you can combine any of them with combined struct:

```golang
type Result struct {
  err error
  msg string
}
```

or

```golang
type Result struct {
  err error
  msg *string // in cases that empty string can be a true result, you can evaluate msg with nil
}
```

---

I should also mention that in some special cases, we don't return the error and just log it there.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    password := "blah blah"
    resultChan := make(chan string)

    go createHashedPassword(password, resultChan)

    // Do some other stuff

    fmt.Println(<-resultChan) // Be careful that it's a blocking code.
}

func createHashedPassword(password string, resultChan chan string) {
    // your code for hashing and stuff
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err) // *** Here we just log the error, or handle it.
    }
    resultChan <- result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps not a good fit here, but a google search led me here and i'm suprised this isnt here.

### Errgroup

Error group is an experimental package similiar to wait group.  and its worth at least being aware of. It works best when you have many go routines.

```
import  "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"

...
g := errgroup.WithContext(ctx) // alternatively errgroup.Group{}

g.Go(func() error {
  //Hash logic here 
})

// do your other stuff.

if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
  // handle error
}
```